# Cannot find solution for Unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am sorry if this is a repetitive question but I feel like I have done everything in every answer that I have found for this problem. I am trying to follow the tutorial on Microsoft's website for creating a Windows Desktop Application and I ran into this. I have checked to see if I made the correct project and I have checked if the subsystem is set to Windows. This is my code.

```
#include <Windows.h>  
#include <tchar.h>
int CALLBACK WinMain(
_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
_In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
_In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
_In_ int       nCmdShow
);

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
_In_ HWND   hwnd,
_In_ UINT   uMsg,
_In_ WPARAM wParam,
_In_ LPARAM lParam
);`
```

And here is my error:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16 referenced in 
function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)  
TextEditor  C:\Users\jcoch\Source\Repos\TextEditor\TextEditor   
\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_wwinmain.obj)
```

Comment: `int CALLBACK WinMain(...);` is a declaration of `WinMain`. It is a promise that somewhere the linker will find a definition of `WinMain`. It is not a definition though, so the linker has nothing to find. Solution: Implement `WinMain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason used entry point and main function does not match. Use `wWinMain` instead `WinMain` or set `WinMainCRTStartup` property in Project Properties -> Linker -> Entry Point (or just add the line `#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup"`to code)